# 2nd order ODE with constant parameters - sine

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general closed form solution for:
$$x''(t)+ax'(t)+bx(t)=c\sin(dt)$$ with $a,b,c,d$ being constant parameters?

The homogeneous solution is straightforward but I'm having trouble with the particular solution (I tried some variations of $y_{p}=A\sin(dt)+B\cos(dt)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna use $\omega t$ instead of $dt$ which looks too much like a differential.

If you tried variations of $y_p = A \sin (\omega t) +  B \cos (\omega t)$ you have come to
$$
-A \omega^2 \sin(\omega t)  -B \omega^2 \cos(\omega t) \\
-aB\omega \sin(\omega t) + aA \omega \cos(\omega t) \\
+Ab \sin (\omega t) + bB \cos (\omega t) = \\
c \sin (\omega t)
$$ Then matching the cosine terms to zero gives $$B = \frac{aA\omega}{\omega^2-b}$$ and plugging this in and matching the sine terms gives
$$ A = \frac{c}{\omega^2+\frac{\omega^2a^2}{1-b}+b}
$$
There are actually two special relations among $(a,b,\omega)$ that invalidate this:  $b=\omega^2$ and $\omega^2+\frac{\omega^2a^2}{1-b}+b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

$$x''(t)+\text{a}x'(t)+\text{b}x(t)=\text{c}\sin(\text{d}t)$$

You can also use Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x''(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}+\text{a}\mathcal{L}_t\left[x'(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}+\text{b}\mathcal{L}_t\left[x(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{c}\mathcal{L}_t\left[\sin(\text{d}t)\right]_{(\text{s})}$$

Use:

1. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x''(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{s}^2\text{X}(\text{s})-\text{s}x(0)-x'(0)$$
2. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x'(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{s}\text{X}(\text{s})-x(0)$$
3. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{X}(\text{s})$$
4. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\sin(\text{d}t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}^2+\text{s}^2}$$

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\text{X}(\text{s})-\text{s}x(0)-x'(0)+\text{a}\left(\text{s}\text{X}(\text{s})-x(0)\right)+\text{b}\text{X}(\text{s})=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}^2+\text{s}^2}$$

Solving for $\text{X}(\text{s})$:

$$\text{X}(\text{s})=\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}^2+\text{s}^2}+x(0)(\text{a}+\text{s})+x'(0)}{\text{b}+\text{s}(\text{a}+\text{s})}$$

Now, with inverse Laplace transform we find you'll find the function $x(t)$.